# how to add @keypress in vue.js v-select

Tags: vue.js

```
<v-select :value.sync="selected" :options="options" @keypress="function()"> 
</v-select>
```

I tried the code above, but it doesn't seem to work.
is this even possible or is there another way?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the `.native` modifier to listen on events of components, so change the the `@keypress=""` to `@keypress.native=""`

Comment: Thanks a lot men for the big help.

Comment: To further add, if using a `bootstra-vue` Form Select, @samayo's answer is also correct. `@keydown.native.ctrl.enter=""` works if you want to listen to Ctrl+Enter events there.

Comment: not work i have tried with .native or native.ctrl.enter  "vue": "2.x",